# What does the phrase "in stark terms" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/H-2q-QMUIgY). It is at 1 minute and 7 second. Here is the context:

> **In the most stark terms**, the absence of food led the deaths, difectly and indirectly, of 20 million peopledufing those years.

I  checked all the meanings of the words in the phrase, but still I cannot get what it means.

Comment: Please don't just say "I checked all the meanings". Instead, include the research in your question and tell us how the definitions you've found don't fit. Always check [multiple dictionaries](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#739) as well.

Comment: The sentence is full of spelling errors.What meanings did you check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that the narrator is speaking in the *strongest* or *most severe* possible terms. He doesn't want to pull any punches.

One meaning of *stark* (The Free Dictionary Online) is

> Severe or unmitigated; harsh or grim

You can see how the deaths of 20 million people might warrant such terms.

Answer (score 1):

**stark** can also mean "with all nuance stripped away; in black-or-white terms with no shades of gray".  The word is being used there to characterize the statement in the main clause, which attributes those 20 million deaths to a *single* cause, starvation from lack of food.